# Set value JQUERY UI Slider with LeaFlet map

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, leaflet, jquery-ui-slider

im willing to modify the time value of the Leaflet TimeSlider plugin, i have this plugin that i modified so i can see in locale format.

https://github.com/carlosign/LeafletSlider-LocalTime/blob/master/src/SliderControl.js

Im willing to modify it with 2 textbox, one for the initial value and the other for the final value, the slider is a range one. I tried to set it with the classic jquery ui.

```
<input type="text" id="amount">
<input type="text" id="amount2">
```

and with JS

```
$("#amount").change(function() {
    $("#leaflet-slider").slider('values',0,$(this).val());
});
$("#amount2").change(function() {
    $("#leaflet-slider").slider('values',1,$(this).val());
});
```

But it doesnt work, the slider wont change its value.

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'

And the slider is initialized with the leaflet map. The inputs are not in the map div.

Comment: What "doesn't work"? When you debug this code with `console.log()`, what is the issue?

Comment: Did you read the error? Did you check what line it's coming from? Get in the habit of reading errors, don't ignore them! Is your `.change()` event firing? Is `$(this).val()` returning a value? }

Comment: I dont understand the error, the slider is initialized before the textbox fires the change event. Also the error line refers to the input tag. If i create a slider with Jquery with the same code, but without leaflet, it works.